# Cannot update parent's state from child component

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a parent component which contains data to build the rows of a table. A child component renders the actual table. Every row should be deletable, so I created a function inside the parent component to update its state and I passed it to the child component, so it could be called on the click of a button.

Even though the setter function is fired the state is not actually changed. The table is not re-rendered and the `useEffect` which has `files` as a dependency is not fired.

I'm not understanding why this happens, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-hooks-c2ebx)'s the problem reproduced in codesandbox. I would be very glad if anyone could help solving this.

Edit: I'm adding the code here since links can break over time, as @UmerAbbas pointed out.

```js
// App.js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Table from "./Table";

export default function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState({
    "mario.jpg": {
      name: "mario.jpg",
      size: 1234
    },
    "luigi.mkv": {
      name: "luigi.mkv",
      size: 1234567
    }
  });
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("files have changed");
    setRows([]);
    const filesKeys = Object.keys(files);
    for (const filename of filesKeys) {
      setRows((prevState) => [
        ...prevState,
        { filename, size: files[filename].size }
      ]);
    }
  }, [files]);

  const handleDelete = (file) => {
    console.log(file);
    const _files = files;
    delete _files[file];
    console.log("Setting files");
    setFiles(_files);
    console.log("files set");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table rows={rows} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
    </div>
  );
}

// Table.jsx
export default function Table({ rows, handleDelete }) {
  return (
    <table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      {rows.map((row) => {
        return (
          <tr key={row.filename}>
            <td>{row.filename}</td>
            <td>{row.size}</td>
            <td>
              <button onClick={() => handleDelete(row.filename)}>Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your ```useEffect``` internally doesn't depend on ```files```. Your code actually works except that you haven't taken care of the 'contextual' part of ```useEffect```. Just place the code that you have written inside ```useEffect``` inside of the ```handleDelete``` method and it should work fine.

Comment: Please add the code in your question, for future reference as links can break.

Comment: @ArjisChakraborty what do you mean with "Your `useEffect` internally doesn't depend on `files`"? `files` is used on line 21 and on line 25 inside `useEffect`. I know from that example it might seem useless to put files in the state, but in the real code I need that object in other functions so I had to put it in the state.

@UmerAbbas You're right, I'm adding the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is actually less severe than you think. In your sandbox, it seems you are attempting to update state directly by not creating a copy of `files` at line 32. Your sandbox works if you do create a shallow copy before making edits to the object:

```
const _files = { ...files };
```

For more information, please see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) (note that though the documentation applies to class-based components the principle also extends to functional components).

Comment: The problem was pretty obvious, but I was apparently too dumb to see. Thanks for the answer, I'm gonna accept yours since you also gave an explanation :)

Comment: Hey we've all made the mistake of directly updating state, no shame!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the function version of set state.

```
const handleDelete = (file) => {
  setFiles((prev) => {
    const { [file]: fileName, ...rest } = prev;
    return rest;
  });
  console.log("files set");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try duplicating an element like this:

```js
  const handleDelete = (file) => {
    const _files = { ...files };  // like this
    delete _files[file];
    setFiles(_files);
  };
```

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-haslett-gxyic?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Indeed it works, but I don't understand why. Would you mind explaining how this is different, so I won't make the same mistake in the future? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Robin `const _files = files;` assigns the reference of the `files` variable to the new `_files` variable. React setState uses [Referential Equity](https://dev.to/tylerthehaas/referential-equality-in-react-127h) to determine if the state needs to be updated or not, here the answer `...` spread operator is used to create a new copy of state object. Now react will updated the state as it's a new object.

Comment: Yeah, it was actually pretty obvious, thanks for the explanation :)